# How to filter out subtrees with certain inherited flags from a tree hierarchy stored via "path" column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark-sql

Imagine a tree hierarchy like this:

```
1
|_ 11
    |_ 111
        |_ 1111
        |_ 1112
    |_ 112
        |_ 1121
        |_ 1122
        |_ 1113
|_ 12
    |_ 121
    |_ 122
    |_ 123
    |_ 124
        |_ 1241
        |_ 1242
        |_ 1243
```

If we have one table which stores IDs and paths:

| id | path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | /1/ |
| 11 | /1/11/ |
| 111 | /1/11/111/ |
| ... | ... |

along with one table which stores a flag 'is_turned_on' for some IDs:

| id | is_turned_on |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | true |
| 111 | true |
| 1121 | false |
| 121 | true |
| 122 | false |
| 1243 | true |

And we assume:

1. Children will inherit 'is_turned_on' from the nearest parent
2. The default case (if an ID does not itself have an explicit DB entry, nor any parent with an explicit DB entry) has 'is_turned_on=true' by default

Is there a way I can use an SQL query to get how many IDs have 'is_turned_on=true' or 'is_turned_on=false'?

Comment: You tagged two different database platforms, please add the correct tag for the database you are using,

Comment: @Stu thanks, have added just postgresql